# Getting permission error when editing hosts file

Tags: python, hosts

Using python, I am trying to edit the hosts file.

```
with open('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', 'r+') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    data[70] = '127.0.0.1 web.alanmrsa.com'
    file.writelines(data)
    print('done')
```

When I run this file, it gives me the following error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] in python`

Comment: Please include the complete error message. It is impossible to tell which statement generated it.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is [writable only by Administrator](https://www.labnol.org/software/edit-hosts-files-as-administrator/13673/). You should run your script as Administrator instead.

Also note that you should do a `file.seek(0)` after `data = file.readlines()` so that you can overwrite the original content, and also do a `file.truncate()` after `file.writelines(data)` so that there would be no leftover characters from the original content in case your replacement string is shorter than the content of the original 71th line.

Comment: How would I go about running as administrator? I’ve tried some of the solutions on stack overflow but they just result in my python exiting

Comment: Try running `cmd` as Administrator first, and then run your script from the command line session.

Comment: It still gives me the following error     with open('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', 'r+') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'

Comment: Try running the script with `runas /user:Administrator path_to_script` in command line.